# homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ to open unit disk.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the open unit disk are homeomophic. This seems obvious as I can easily stretch the disk into the real plane, but I cannot think of a way to analytically do it. Does $$f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)) =(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}). $$ get the job done?

Comment: What is $f(0,0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You proposed homeomorphism doesn't quite work because it is not continuous at 0. Try instead proving that $$f (x)=\frac {x}{\Vert x\Vert+1} $$ does the job.

Comment: Is $x$ a vector?

Comment: It is an element of $\mathbb R^2. $

Comment: awesome, thanks. So I need to show that there is a continuous bijection from $C=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2| ||x||<1\}$. I study this as a hobby and am not too familiar with the way to do this. Any references you can point me to?

Comment: Not knowing your background, it is hard to say. I learned this material from Munkres' Topology, but there are other options. Looking at other questions and answers on MSE about homeomorphism would also help.

Comment: wait! I got it! What if I map $(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto e^x$? Then would this work?

Comment: So that is certainly a bijection of $(0,\infty) $ and $\mathbb R $, but it will take a bit more work to adapt this to the problem at hand.

Comment: Observe that for real y, the map f(y)=y/(1+|y|)  is a homeomorphism of $R$ to (-1,1). Identify $R$ with the $x$-axis in $R^2$ and apply a similar kind of map to every line thru the origin. which is gives   the Alex S function.

Comment: Wait, now I am confused. What do you mean by identify with? (glue perhaps?) Perhaps a proof will straighten things up--which would consist of generating a continuous bijection from the open disk to the real plane. I don't see how the above function does this. Can you elaborate? I am new :D

Comment: This comment chain is getting kind of long. Why don't you ask a new question asking for a proof, and I will explain how it is done.