# Explicit Homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to open disk

Tags: general-topology

I already asked a question here [homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ to open unit disk.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709723/homeomorphism-from-mathbbr2-to-open-unit-disk/1709734?noredirect=1#comment3489391_1709734)
I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2 \cong  \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2<1\}$ The function that apparently solves this is $$f(z)=\frac{z}{||z||+1}$$
for $z\in \mathbb{R}^2$.  In order to show this, I need to prove that $f$ is a continuous bijection. Continuity is obvious, but I see no reason why this is a bijection-- I also see no reason why it should have a continuous inverse. Can someone explain this to me/point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: What does the function $f$ do? It takes a vector, then it "scales" it by $||z||+1$. Thus, if the images of two vectors are the same, then they have the same direction. Notice that the norm of $f(z)$ is $1-\frac{1}{||z||+1}$. Use this to show that if the image of two vectors are the same, then their norms are the same, which means that the vectors are the same (since they also have the same direction). For surjectivity, try to understand what happens to $||f(z)||$ when $||z||$ is very large.

Comment: Note $z$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, not $\mathbb{R}$. I've made this change.

Answer (score 3):

Solve it directly. That is, solve $w = {z \over 1+ \|z\|}$ for $z$.

We see that $w=0$ **iff** $z=0$.

It is clear that $w$ and $z$ lie on the same line, so we can look for $z$ of the form $tw$ such that
$w = {tw \over 1+ \|tw\|}$. It should be clear that if $w \neq 0$ then $t \ge 0$.

Then we have $1+t \|w\| = t$ and so $t={1 \over 1-\|w\|}$, from which we get
$g(w) = {w \over 1-\|w\|}$.

We have $g(0) = 0$, $g$ is continuous, and we have $g(f(z)) = z$. It follows
that $f$ is bijective.