# Prove that the unit disk is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I have been stuck on this problem and am not quite sure where to begin. Based on my readings I am aware an analytic function exists, but I am not sure how that is derived. How would one go about showing the two spaces are homeomorphic?

Comment: Take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709808/explicit-homeomorphism-from-mathbbr2-to-open-disk

Comment: @PAM1499 I took a look at that, but I'm not sure how they came up with that function to begin with.

Comment: Start by looking for a strictly increasing function from $(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Notice that in $\mathbb{R}$ you have $f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|+1}$ an homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-1,1)$

Comment: @copper.hat Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: Well, there is no recipe. The map $x \mapsto {x \over 1+|x|}$ maps the real line to $(-1,1)$. Then I replaced the $|x|$ by $\|x\|$ ...

Comment: @copper.hat So if asked to show the two spaces are homeomorphic, one can just reference this equation? I'm confused how to rigorously show this if asked on an exam.

Comment: @WBSS You would need to show that it is a bijection.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you know of any link that shows this?

Comment: @WBSS: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1709821/27978 :-)

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you!

Comment: The sad part is I was going to answer this, I forgot I had answered it a long time ago, but @PAM1499's link found it.